# Flameshot not working after update

Tags: screenshot

When I hit `Take Screenshot` item from the Flameshot menu, now it pops what I guess is the native Ubuntu screenshot tool, instead of the Flameshot one.

To be fair, I don't know what was the update affecting it. All I know is that it has been working flawlessly for years and now it suddenly stopped working, and it makes me sad.

In case it helps:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

BTW, it also happens if I use the console command:

```
$ flameshot gui
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket
flameshot: error: Unable to capture screen
flameshot: error: Unable to capture screen
flameshot: info: Screenshot aborted.
```

I would provide a screenshot, but I don't like the native tool for doing that.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks it was just a new intermediate dialog. I panicked when it didn't show Flameshot UI, but all you have to do is click on the "Share" button, to let Flameshot receive the screen data.

[image: Intermediate dialog]